# Trigger in oracle sql

Tags: database, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE INVOICE
(
INVOICE_NUMBER NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
QUOTATION_NUMBER NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
STAFF_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
INVOICE_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
INVOICE_BALANCE NUMBER(10,2) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (QUOTATION_NUMBER) REFERENCES QUOTATION(QUOTATION_NUMBER),
FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTOMER_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (STAFF_ID) REFERENCES STAFF(STAFF_ID),
CONSTRAINT INVOICE_BALANCE_CK CHECK (INVOICE_BALANCE>=0)
);

CREATE TABLE QUOTATION_DETAIL
(
QUOTATION_NUMBER NUMBER(10),
PRODUCT_CODE NUMBER(10),
PRODUCT_SELL_QUANTITY NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (QUOTATION_NUMBER,PRODUCT_CODE),
FOREIGN KEY (QUOTATION_NUMBER) REFERENCES QUOTATION(QUOTATION_NUMBER),
FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT_CODE) REFERENCES PRODUCT(PRODUCT_CODE),
CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_SELL_QUANTITY_CK CHECK (PRODUCT_SELL_QUANTITY>0)
);

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT
(
PRODUCT_CODE NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
PRODUCT_QUANTITY NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
PRODUCT_MANUFACTURER_PRICE NUMBER(10,2) NOT NULL,
PRODUCT_SELLING_PRICE NUMBER(10,2) NOT NULL,
PRODUCT_WARRANTY NUMBER(5),
PRODUCT_WEIGHT NUMBER(5,2),
PRODUCT_LENGTH VARCHAR2(30),
PRODUCT_WIDTH VARCHAR2(30),
PRODUCT_HEIGHT VARCHAR2(30),
PRODUCT_MATERIAL VARCHAR2(30),
MANUFACTURER_COUNTRY VARCHAR2(20),
PRODUCT_REMARK VARCHAR2(100),
SUPPLIER_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
PRODUCT_CATEGORY_NUMBER NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (SUPPLIER_ID) REFERENCES SUPPLIER(SUPPLIER_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT_CATEGORY_NUMBER) REFERENCES PRODUCT_CATEGORY(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_NUMBER)
);
```

I want to create a trigger which after invoice is inserted, the `PRODUCT_QUANTITY` in `PRODUCT` will decrease by the `PRODUCT_SELL_QUANTITY` in `QUOTATION_DETAIL`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHANGE
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF INVOICE_NUMBER ON INVOICE
DECLARE
TEMP_QUOTATION_NUMBER NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
SELECT QUOTATION_NUMBER INTO TEMP_QUOTATION_NUMBER FROM INVOICE WHERE
INVOICE_NUMBER = (SELECT MAX(INVOICE_NUMBER) FROM INVOICE);
UPDATE PRODUCT
SET PRODUCT.PRODUCT_QUANTITY = PRODUCT.PRODUCT_QUANTITY -
QUOTATION_DETAIL.PRODUCT_SELL_QUANTITY
WHERE QUOTATION_NUMBER = TEMP_QUOTATION_NUMBER AND PRODUCT.PRODUCT_CODE =  
QUOTATION_DETAIL.PRODUCT_CODE;
END;
```

When I run it , it shows

```
Trigger PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHANGE compiled
Errors: check compiler log
Error(5,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(7,75): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "QUOTATION_DETAIL"."PRODUCT_CODE": invalid
identifier
```

Comment: Please show us your attempt at writing the trigger.

Comment: Have you tested that UPDATE SQL outside of the trigger?

Comment: Your update statement does not now what is quotation_detail.
You possibly wanted to use :NEW.PRODUCT_CODE (and [referencing construct from the trigger definition] (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm)).
BTW. If you have many invoices than your may have poor performance and locks (possible deadlocks).

Comment: Yes, Grzegorz Kazior -- which is why I suggested testing the UPDATE outside of the trigger.  It would have failed and he could re-write correctly.  The issue is with that UPDATE SQL and the quotation_detail table.  Review UPDATE syntax/usage in Oracle docs please.